# Running a python script from shell

Tags: python, shell

I want to run a python script from a shell script. I have been able to run it from the "command window" (Cygwin), but now I want to be able to call it from a shell script. It does not work the way I thought it would and the Internet has not really helped me with it.

My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
python Calibrate.py
```

I hope someone could help me further. *Calibrate* just contains a few basic command lines to transform some data that has been read in with an excelreader in the script itself.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it does not work". Do you get an error message?

Comment: These are the errors I get: ': 

[Errno 2] No such file or directoryle 'Calibrate.py

./test.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found

While the script is in the directory I am currently in according to my command window.

Comment: Calibrate.py doesn't seem to be in the same path as where you run the script.

Comment: The code you posted only shows two lines, yet the error in `test.sh` is on line 4.   Please show your exact code (that sounds like a spacing problem, by the way).  Check that `Calibrate.py` is in the current directory, preferably use the full path name for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the python executable is in your PATH environment variable, then add in your script

In the file job.sh,

`#!/bin/sh
 python <path/to/python/script>/python_script.py`

Execute this command to make the script runnable for you : `chmod u+x job.sh`
Run it : `./job.sh`

Answer (score 1):

A Bash script needs to use the Unix EOL (End Of Line) convention, which terminates each line with `\n`. But it looks like your test.sh shell script file uses the Windows / DOS EOL convention, which terminates each line with `\r\n`.

You need to get rid of those `\r` characters in test.sh, and you need to set your editor to use Unix line endings.

A simple way to strip `\r` out of a file is to use the Unix `sed` command; I assume it's available in Cygwin:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' test.sh
```

This removes all `\r` characters in test.sh, writing the result back to test.sh